# Operadores matemáticos e lógicos no Visualg

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, operadores, visualg

Por que os códigos destacados em asterisco não funcionam da maneira que escolhi?

Eu percebi que usando o número menor primeiro e o maior segundo, funciona normalmente, mas fiquei encucada para saber porque está errado.

```
   algoritmo "semnome"
var
   nota1, nota2, media: real
inicio
      Escreval ("--------------------------")
      Escreval ("ESCOLA TIO PATINHO CRACUDO")
      Escreval ("--------------------------")
      Escreval ("Digite a primeira nota: ")
      Leia (nota1)
      Escreval ("Digite a segunda nota: ")
      Leia (nota2)
      media <- (nota1 + nota2) / 2
      Se **(media >=10) e (media <9)** entao
         Escreval ("Média: ",media)
         Escreval ("Aproveitamento: A")
      senao
           Se **(media >=9) e (media <8)** entao
              Escreval ("Média: ",media)
              Escreval ("Aproveitamento: B")
      senao
              Se **(media >=8) e (media <7)** entao
                 Escreval ("Média: ",media)
                 Escreval ("Aproveitamento C")
      senao
                 Se **(media >=7) e (media <6)** entao
                    Escreval ("Média: ",media)
                    Escreval ("Aproveitamento D")
      senao
                    Se **(media >=6) e (media <5)** entao
                       Escreval ("Média: ",media)
                       Escreval ("Aproveitamento E")
      senao
                          **Se (media <4) entao**
                          Escreval ("Média: ",media)
                          Escreval ("Aproveitamento F")
                                                 FimSe
                                        FimSe
                                FimSe
                          FimSe
                  FimSe
              FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos deixar um pouco mais português do que está:

Se media for mais ou igual a **E** media for menor que 8.

Então as duas comparações devem ser verdadeiras para que toda a expressão ser verdadeira, esta é a função do operador relacional `e` (que costuma ser `and` ou `&&` em linguagens reais).

Vamos dizer que o número seja maior ou igual a 9, então é verdadeiro. Então esse número pode ser 9, 10, 11, 12 ou 13, ou qualquer outro número nessa sequência. Mas ele não pode ser 8, ou 7, ou menor que isso, certo?

Aí, sabendo disso, ele vai na segunda comparação e já podemos concluir que ela será falsa, correto?

Se uma é verdadeira e a outra é falsa, como o todo pode ser verdadeiro depois que aplica o operador `e`? Não tem como em situação alguma.

Na sua pergunta é falado:

> não funcionam da maneira que escolhi

Fica até complicado falarmos qual é o certo porque a pergunta diz que escolheu algo, mas só você sabe o que foi escolhido. Não há uma definição clara do que desejava fazer.

Eu tentei inferir o que deveria ser, mas não parece ter lógica dentro do conhecimento que tenho de classificações de nota. O A deveria ser só de uma nota para cima, então não sei porque compara com o 8. O B deveria começar de uma nota mais baixa e ir até uma um pouco mais alta, e assim por diante. O código tenta considerar B para uma nota acima de 8 e abaixo de 7, não faz sentido.

Quem sabe queria fazer:

```
Se media > 7 e media <= 8 entao
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Grade.ptg).

Também não deveria fazer tantas indentações, um nível basta, imagina se tivesse mais comparações, onde esse código ia parar?